# ShowDialog and Show sometimes throw exception with animated closing window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, storyboard

Im creating a small application for a few friends. The application is done, but I want to make the GUI of it more "professional" so Im making a new GUI to it.
Ive stumbled across a weird issue with one of the dialogboxes Im using for data input where sometimes when I use the Close() funcion on it, the showDialog function will sometimes throw a InvalidOperationException with the text "This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource".
If I write the ShowDialog function call in a try catch and catch the exception to prevent it from stopping the application runtime, it works fine and the window in question can still open and close as intended, but it sometimes throws that exception.

The code for opening the window as a dialog (Run from mainwindow on button click):

```
addCommand win = new addCommand();      //Creates a new instance of the window
win.Left = this.Left;                   //Makes it appear on top of the mainwindow
win.Top = this.Top + 25;

((BlurEffect)appMain.Effect).Radius = 5;//Blurs out the background (Error occurs even with this not added
win.ShowDialog();                   //Shows window as dialog (This is where the exception is thrown
((BlurEffect)appMain.Effect).Radius = 0;//Removes blur when window is closed
```

Code in the window class:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}

private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (!animationComplete)
   {
      Storyboard sb = Resources["closingAnimation"] as Storyboard;
      sb.Begin(this);
      e.Cancel = true;
   }
}

private void storyboardComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   animationComplete = true;
   this.Close();
}
```

A button closes the window to trigger ShowDialog to continue runtime. If the animation has not been played, it cancels the Close and plays the animation, which on completition runs Close again, but with animationComplete set true and allowing the window to close. The animation is a simple doubleanimation adjust height of the window from 92 to 0 to create a "slide in, slide out" effect on the window.

This works something like 50/50. Sometimes it works, other times it throws the exception. Im not sure why it sometimes throws the exception and sometimes not. It seems random.

StackTrace of the exception

```
StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.PointToScreen(Point point)\r\n   at
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow.UpdatePlacement()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow.<UpdatePlacementAsync>b__77_0(Object obj)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)\r\n   at 
MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)\r\n   at 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   
at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n   at
 MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Window.Show()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()\r\n   
at Gigglerekt_Scenebot_v2_GUI_update.MainWindow.btnAddCommand_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\\Development\\C#\\Gigglerekt Scenebot v2 GUI update\\Gigglerekt Scenebot v2 GUI update\\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 84\r\n   at
 System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)\r\n   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)\r\n   
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)\r\n   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   at 
MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)\r\n   at
 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)\r\n   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n   at
 MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)\r\n   at
 System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)\r\n   at 
System.Windows.Application.Run()\r\n   at 
Gigglerekt_Scenebot_v2_GUI_update.App.Main()"   string
```

**Update** WindowStyle is set to none, but if I set it to something else (Tested with ToolWindow) the exception LOOKS to not be happening anymore.. Testing more to see if I just got lucky or what happened

**Update 2** It does indeed look like exception is gone when windowstyle is NOT set to NONE. This goes regardless if I trigger the closing animation with the windows' X button or the button I have added that closes the window

**Update 3** If I instead of closing the window on animation complete, hide it. Then close it in the parent window after it resumes runtime (ShowDialog continues on hidden window as well apperantly), the exception does no longer occur. So until I find out why closing it immediately after animation is done does not work all the time with none windowstyle I guess its a workaround? So a question would be what happens on Close() when WindowStyle is set to None, compared to when WindowStyle is not set to None?

Comment: I bet the animation is still running when you try to close the dialog

Comment: @Aaron.S - but he is dealing with that in his form_closing event handler.

Comment: wait for the animation to complete and then close dialog, I bet it never causes an exception, but if you close before its finished animating then you get your exception

Comment: assuming he is properly setting that Boolean flag then yes its being handled

Comment: Have you tried opening the dialog with `win.ShowDialog(this);` instead of just `win.ShowDialog();`?  It may be a problem with not having a parent, although it shouldn't do that.

Comment: is that exception complete?  it appears truncated

Comment: That is the whole stacktrace presented to me from Visual Studio yes

Comment: Try calling the dialog with the owner specified - `win.ShowDialog(this);`.  I don't know why it would cause this exception, but I've never used the ShowDialog without it.

Comment: Commented on the answer below. I cant do that as there is no showdialog that takes window as parameter, but I have tried setting owner with win.owner = this and it makes no difference. Just to make sure I changed the constructor to take Mainwindow as a parameter and set owner on initialization. Just as win.owner = this, it made no difference

Comment: ShowDialog takes no parameter BUT Show does

Comment: There is a showdialog that takes your main window as a parameter - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx, but if that does not solve the problem, then we are back to ...

Comment: Show does not halt the program in the background until it closes which is the reason I use ShowDialog

Comment: @Aaron.S - that is not accurate.  ShowDialog can take no parameter or it can also take the owner window as a parameter,  same as the Show method.

Comment: I see I didnt specify, but this is not a Forms application, it is a WPF application. Not sure if that changes your answers?

Comment: In that case (and I should have noticed you had WPF in your tags), neither Show, nor ShowDialog take a parameter.  Which makes my comment pretty useless.

Comment: yes you are correct, msdn confuses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One more thing, inside the form_closing event handler, you are checking `if (!animationComplete)` and apparently starting the animation which then truly closes the dialog when it completes.  Do you ever set that `animationComplete` to false?  Perhaps in this dialog's load event?

Comment: It has to do with the animation and I guess cancelling the window closing to play the animation because if I remove the animation it does not throw an exception anymore. I tried instead of calling Close on button click and cancelling this to play the animation, just playing the animation with on Completion runs the storyboardComplete function which closes the window (See initial post) and this still produces the exception

Comment: @AgapwIesu yes it is set to false on creation. I could try to set it to false again in the constructor, but I imagine that would make no difference

Comment: What do you mean "on creation"?  Is this a global that you set in the parent window? or is it a property of this dialog that gets set... where?

Comment: its a private bool set in the class of the window causing this issue. not the main window. Im sorry if Im not making sense sometimes. The coding I know is selflearnt and not all the terms and names is familiar to me.

Comment: Ok, I am posting a solution.  try it and we'll see if it works.

Comment: Interestingly enough if I change windowstyle to toolwindow. The exception looks to be gone... Editing original post

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx

```
win.Show(this);
```

the owner (form that spawned the dialog) is not aware that it was closed, setting the owner for this dialog will inform the owner that it closed.

Comment: Wow, right after I put it in a comment.  Not cool to grab someone else's suggestion as your answer!

Comment: sorry I didn't refresh to see your comment

Comment: There is no overload of ShowDialog that takes a window as parameter, but I did try to set owner with win.owner = this because I used it for positioning initially and it did nothing

Comment: yeah, right, it just happened to occur to you a minute after I posted my comment, and even using the wrong terminology I used in my comment - i.e. that is not a parent, but more precisely, it is the owner.

Comment: post the answer and I will delete mine, no biggy, I am not a point hog, you can take this one

Comment: Also wouldnt that mean the exception would be thrown every time the window closes? It does works about 50% of the time without exception

Comment: Not necessarily.  Not having an owner, combined with what you are doing in the form_closing event handler might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `Button_Click` is the event handler for your close button. 
 So, change your code like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Storyboard sb = Resources["closingAnimation"] as Storyboard;
      sb.Completed += new EventHandler(storyboardComplete);
      sb.Begin(this);
}

private void storyboardComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}
```

and eliminate the Window_Closing event handler.  It's been a while since I worked with WPF, so I am assuming that ShowDialog does not give you the "X" close button at the top right of the window, so all you have to worry about is your own close button.  And what you want to do when they press that close button is start the animation, and it is actually the end of the animation that really closes the dialog, so leave the `this.Close()` to occur only on the storyboardComplete event.

Comment: This makes no difference. The window I am showing has a windowStyle set to none for the purpose of easier customizing it to fit the rest of the application.

Comment: what event do you have connected to the method `storyboardComplete`.  I am assuming you are using this handler for the `Completed` event.

Comment: How are you defining that?  I just added a line to the code to explicitly set the Completed event handler to be that method, but since that line was not there in your code that created the storyboard, how was it ever getting set?

Comment: its set in the XAML <Storyboard x:Key="closingAnimation" Completed="storyboardComplete">. Tried moving it to the DoubleAnimation tag instead, but this makes no difference

Comment: Not sure about the rules of this, but I could archive the project and share it here. its currently just a mainwindow with that window on it and a button for it. May make it easier to troubleshoot for you?

Comment: Made a update to main post, but it looks like its related to the windowstyle being set to none because when I set it to something else. It works with animation and no exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Windowstyle to anything but None allows the window to close without exception being thrown, but this would make the reason for me creating a window for dialog in the first place obsolete.

The fix for this I found for now is making the animation Hide window and in the parent window close it after ShowDialog resumes runtime. The exception does not happen, even with WindowStyle set to none.